# Writing url in View in Django

Tags: python, html, django, folium

I want to define a link for a character in the view.
I used the following code, but it has an error.
Error: Encountered unknown tag 'url'

code:

```
            html="""
                 <p>
                  <a href="{% url index2 %}">more information</a>
                 </p>
                """
```

I use the Folium library and want to put a link in the popup.
So I can not use the normal mode and I have used the above method.

Comment: Hey. Why do you want to use a template tag inside normal Python code? Why not just use Python syntax to insert the URL into that HTML partial? e.g. use `format_html()` to create the HTML and `reverse()` to get the URL.

Comment: Hey.
The explanation is a bit complicated.
never mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have template tags in your HTML, so you have to pass it through the Django template processor:

```
from django.template import Template, Context

html = Template(
    """
    <p>
    <a href="{% url index2 %}">more information</a>
    </p>
    """).render(Context({}))
```

Note that extra spaces included in your quoted string will appear in the html output.

Also note that I am passing an empty dictionary to construct the `Context`, but if you were to put some entries into that dictionary, they would be available as template variables in the template.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make entry in URL.py with url index2/ and view.{function in view you want to call to execute on clicl}